# Is that possible to use string interpolation format composite formatting between escaped curly braces?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, format-string

I want to build string with formatted value between escaped curly braces ("{{" and "}}").

I would prefer use the **format string** instead of ToString() method to format the value.

```
    //Works fine but don't use composite format string
    $"{{{Math.PI.ToString("n2")}}}" // return {3.14}

    //Use composite format string but does not work
    $"{{{Math.PI:n2}}} // return {n2}

    //Use composite format string but does not work
    $"{{{null:n2}}} // return {

    //Use composite format string, work fine but I do not want extra space
    $"{{{Math.PI:n2} }} // return {3.14 }
```

Comment: What is it you're calling composite formatting? The "n2"? Because your first example is indeed using that formatting. Change it to `$"{{{Math.PI.ToString("n3")}}}"` and it will output `{3.142}` as expected. But if you really must have it next to Math.PI, you could use `$"{{{$"{Math.PI:n3}"}}}"`, but it's kind of silly, in my opinion.

Comment: You _could_ work around it with something like this `$"{{{Math.PI:n2}\x200b}}"`, but I kind of hate it.

Comment: `$"{{{Math.PI:n2}{'}'}";`

Comment: You might take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#escaping-braces

Comment: Here's another abomination: `$"{{{Math.PI:n2}{null}}}"`

Comment: I don't have a solution to this, but I think it's worth focusing on what `String.Format` does - this isn't really about interpolated string literals. `string.Format("{{{Math.PI:n2}}}");` returns `{n2}` as well, which is the problem. If we can solve that, we can probably solve it for interpolated string literals as well - and thinking about `string.Format` we at least don't need to worry about what the compiler will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FormattableString` conversion from an interpolated string to call a custom IFormatter to fix the issue. Unfortunately you can't use an extension method because the implicit conversion from interpolated string to `FormattableString` doesn't occur for the target of an extension method.

```
public class HandleBraces : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider) =>
        (format != null && format.EndsWith("}")) ? String.Format($"{{0:{format.Substring(0, format.Length - 1)}{'}'}", arg) + "}"
                                                 : null;

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType) => this;

    static HandleBraces HBFormatter = new HandleBraces();
    public static string Fix(FormattableString fs) => fs.ToString(HBFormatter);
}
```

Now you can use `Fix`:

```
Console.WriteLine(HandleBraces.Fix($"{{{Math.PI:n2}}}"));
```